# postgresql dblink_connect timeout

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use dblink to move data from one system to another.  Both machines are `RHEL 5.11`, both running `postgresql 9.2`, both on the corp internal net with no firewall rules between them.  I am working from my desktop vpn'ed into the corp internal net.

Call the two machines `FROM` and `TO`.  The FROM machine has dblink installed as an extension, the TO machine does not.  For both machines the user I am specifying has a pg_hba.conf host entry listing `all` for db's, `0.0.0.0/0` for address, and `trust`.

Using `pgadmin3`, I can connect to both machines from my desktop, see/add/modify databases on both.  I think this rules out both trivial connection issues and permissions as potential sources of the problem.

in a `pgadmin` query window for the `FROM` machine, I execute this:

`SELECT dblink_connect('AAA','host=TO dbname=XXX user=postgres password=ZZZ');`

-OR-

`SELECT dblink_connect('host=TO dbname=XXX user=postgres password=ZZZ');`

-OR-

Either variety above entered at a `psql` command line on the `FROM` machine.

Results in this message delivered in the messages-pane or to the command line:

> ----- ERROR:  could not establish connection DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out   Is the server running on host
>   "TO" (AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD) and accepting  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: could not establish connection SQL state: 08001
>
> Detail: could not connect to server: Connection timed out     Is the
>   server running on host "TO" (AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD) and accepting   TCP/IP
>
> ### connections on port 5432?

Suggestions?

Update 
-- tried replacing hostname "TO" with "localhost", same result.
-- however, dblink_connect('dbname_on_FROM'); works. so basic dblink functionality IS functionaing.
-- original problem remains unsolved as I want to ship data to a server on TO machine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you were able to figure out the problem or not, but I am going to answer anyway. The "TO" machine's database might be running on a `port` different than 5432. You need to make sure the port your DB Server is running on and the port you specified in the "FROM" machine are the **same**.

If the port number is same, then there has to be a mistake in `host`, `username` or `password` when specifying these parameters in the "FROM" machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

And my dblink is in  the same instance.
So,I use `127.0.0.1` as my `host`.

when I use `5432` as the `port`;I got time out error.

So,I use `show port` command get the real port of pg host.
I got the result is `3002`;

When I change the `dblink_connect` `port` to `3002`,I can connect success;

So,If you can use a port connect to db from your backend;

And get timeout error in `dblink_connect`.

May,you can try use another port (by use `show port` query) connect db inside.